# Angle between plane and plane is the angle between the two normals.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My professor said the "Angle between a plane and plane is the angle between the normals of those two planes". Then he demonstrated with a notebook, markers, and a desk. I was kind of able to lean on the side that his statement is true. But I'm not satisfied. I didn't really see it was definitely true for his example. Furthermore how do I know this is true for all pairs of planes?

Comment: The angle between planes is $defined$ to be the angle between normal vectors.  Pick a point on the intersection between the planes, and compare the normals

Comment: How do I know this definition is consistent with the definition that what we use in everyday life? @danielson

Comment: If you pick two vectors, one in each plane, that are parallel with each other, the angle between them is the same as the angle between the normals.

Comment: Pick a point in the intersection and find the minimum of the angles between pairs of unit vectors at that point, one in one plane and one in the other. Under what conditions do you get this minimum? How does this condition relate to the normals?